# There are any form to know if a POST is coming from an android application?

Tags: php, android, post

I have a file in PHP receiving a POST from an Android application and it works correctly but it also works correctly if loaded from a browser. What would be the most correct and efficient way to prohibit this from happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add header while making the HTTP request.

e.g. Application Type

```
 httppost.setHeader("Application-Type", "ANDROID");
```

This will differentiate between your calls and server may get to know if call is made from mobile with having this header while Browser doesn't.

Answer (score 3):

Try testing for the user agent in the request `$_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]`. With PHP you can use the get_browser() for more information given the user agent.

Note that any client could send fake a user agent, so this information is good hint, but as any user input, it must not be trusted completely.

If you own the Android application I would suggest sending a security token generated on the android app via HTTPS to your PHP app where it would be validated.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at a page with phpinfo() on that from the android

You can check the Browser and OS, based on that you can chose what to do

Comment: This data can be easily changed by user so don't trust it.